# jQuery delay and hide element

Tags: jquery

Why doesn't the following work?  How do I click an element, hide it for a bit, and then show it?
http://jsfiddle.net/ba8bJ/

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {$(this).hide().delay(800).show()});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hide()` and `show()` only use the animation queue if a duration is specified.

You can provide a duration of `0` and simply write:

```
$("#myButton").click(function() {
    $(this).hide(0).delay(800).show(0);
});
```

You will find an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ba8bJ/3/).

Comment: Thanks Frederic.  Ah, this is what I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, `delay()` is for animations. Use `setTimeout()` instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/rGqpn/

```
$('#myButton').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this).hide();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $this.show();
    }, 800);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jason,  I would think that hide/show limited animation, but evidently it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#myButton').click(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(0).delay(800).fadeIn(0)
});
```

Delay only works for animations/queried functions

Comment: Thanks Spokey,  This is probably what I will end up doing, even though Jason's answer more answered my misguided question.

Answer (score 1):

Pass a duration to show() and hide() because when a duration is provided, `.show()` becomes an animation method.:

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function() {
    $(this).hide(0).delay(800).show(0);
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b26WV/)**